# grabbing and merging multi screenshots using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg

is there a way using FFMPEG to grab multiple screenshots from a video and then merge e.g 8 screens into on image?

for example the end result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Sure, but it's beyond the scope of stackoverflow. Break down each steps, extract the screens [this will help](https://github.com/lcherone/php-ffmpeg-thumbnail-example/blob/master/ffmpeg.php#L36), then build an [image/collage from the screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913943/image-collage-in-php).

Comment: See [tile filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile).

Comment: ^ or that looks simpler...